# Drupal: custom external links in user profile

Tags: drupal, hyperlink, profile, external-links

I have Drupal 7 and want to get custom links to several social networks and other pages in the user profiles.

How this should work:

1. User opens his account settings and sees, for example: Net 1 Nick, Net 2 Nick and other fields. He inputs and saves that info.
2. Now his profile should have several links with title %Net 1 Nick% (or just "Net 1 Account" without any modifications in any user's profile) and URL "http://net1.com/user/%Net 1 Nick%".

So the problem is how to define that prefixes (like "http://net1.com/user/") for each profile link field in a way that user can not change it AND gets working link just entering his nick. I've tried [Link module](http://drupal.org/project/link) but it doesn't have necessary functionality as I can see.

What should I do? Try any other modules? Or can I change this behaviour with custom theme (I will create it by myself, but have never done it before)?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the "[Follow](http://drupal.org/project/follow)" module, which allows users to add their accounts on various social networks, which you can then display as links in a block that's activated by the module (and can be associated with content they create, etc)

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Thanks! I know this module (and that officially there is not possibility to change networks right now), but haven't look into it. *Always use the source, Luke*. It's very easy to improve it :).